# Read file without delimiters (as a single column) in SAS

Tags: sas

I have an xml file that I need to read as a single column table. Now, to achieve the result I embed following line into INFILE statement:

```
dlmstr='nodlmstr'
```

I have not found any appropriate option that would let me do it more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need an option at all.  Just create your 1 variable with enough length to hold the line.

```
data _null_;
file "c:\temp\test.xml";
put "<a>";
put "  <aa>1 </aa>";
put "  <bb>2</bb>";
put "</a>";
run;

data test;
infile "c:\temp\test.xml";
format line $2000.;
input;
line = _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: If I add a blank into second line of your example file (<aa>1</aa>) so that it would become (<aa>1 </aa>) then SAS truncates column at where blank is encountered.

Comment: updated.  Use the `_infile_` automatic variable and assign it to your variable.  Seems to fix the issue.